# SSLRequire syntax problems

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm trying to use SSLRequire to ensure that only certificates with an email from a specific domain are accepted. This is my `SSLRequire` statement, inside a `.htaccess` file:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} =~ m/^.+@example\.com$/
```

However, with this line, Apache complains:

```
SSLRequire: syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offshored the whole `.htaccess` to the main server config (inside a `<Directory>` block) and the problem vanished, so either I missed something or that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.cacert.org/ApacheServerClientCertificateAuthentication

Sometime you want to say - yes accept any certificate from CAcert that has an email of @example.com and not worry about maintaining long lists. This is possible as follows:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
```

A full list is here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire. Sometime certificates can contain more that one email so:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
          or %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email_0} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
          or %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email_1} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
          or %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email_2} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
          or %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email_3} =~ m/^[^@]*@example\.com$/
```

You should change your error message (above) to say that certificates for @example.com are required also.

Comment: I don't see the fundamental difference between your `SSLRequire` line and mine. Why would my `SSLRequire` cause a syntax error but not yours? This is especially intriguing to me, especially since moving the directive to the main server config "solved" the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire), SSLRequire has since been deprecated.

Comment: Not in [apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) which this 5 year old question pertains to ...